# drawing of chemical structures -Any plugin in C# for these?

Tags: c#, chemistry, openbabel

I want to represent the chemical structure drawing in my windows application. I found some softwares are available in the market like "BKChem","Metlab","ChemDraw","SMILE (Simplified molecular input line entry specification)","BioChemDraw". but unfortunately i am unable to found any of above's plug in/API's with dot net please let me know. this is very high priority for me for now.

Comment: Change the title to include `drawing of chemical structures` then its easier for visitors to notice the question even if they are not them selves C# users, they still might know of a good library :)

Comment: [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025800/how-to-render-chemical-reactions-in-windows-forms) it discusses the same problem.

Comment: Why the triple post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038811/chemical-structure-drawing-in-c-windows-forms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025800/how-to-render-chemical-reactions-in-windows-forms

Comment: here i am asking for the API or plugins for suggested answers in my previous posts

Comment: Third time in a week you hit my `chemistry` filter with the same question. Your questions are short, under-detailed, strict-minded. Don't make triple post. If you want to bump your question to the top of the list, just add details, explain what you tried, give time to people to answer.

Comment: @shellholic: I think you didn't read this post properly. my suggestion is read it once. I asked twice for sorry. Now this is third time. Sorry .. Sorry Sorry..ok with you sir ? and filters are there only for hit them , search against them. if you want to secure your filters please don't create it again

Comment: My point is that answers would be more interesting if you completed a single question. There will be synergistic effort. By spiting your questions and being too specific, you miss a great point of the stackoverflow process. I would really help you if I could, but I don't as you "whine",  as you want a premade solution, as you want a `.net` solution and I'm not an expert at it. I could help you with how to draw a structure on screen from scratch given you had some knowledge in drawing. Missing: What is your chemistry level? What are your input? Do you only want to draw or also to edit?

Comment: Sorry, i was rude. my mistake. and thanks for show my place. anyways.Chemestry Level in graduation level. i want to draw shapes  on any key combination . it should generate the image accordingly.

Comment: Take a look here for reference http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html

Comment: Don't apologize, I was also a bit rude. Wait until I write some answer, it's not really a strict `.net` one, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: Kudos @shellholic & OP, you both realized quickly & got your focus back to the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm not at all a .net expert

In the field of chemical structure conversion and drawing, [OpenBabel](http://openbabel.org/) is really the broadest. Unfortunately for you, I only used it from command line, never through API.

BUT, there is a C# API for OpenBabel documented [here](http://openbabel.org/docs/2.3.0/UseTheLibrary/CSharp.html). And it seams that it [can](http://openbabel.org/docs/dev/FileFormats/SVG_2D_depiction.html) output SVG which is an open drawing standard.

Comment: Thanks , Ihave downloaded the required dll. that zip dir has on example cs file. while executing it i am getting the exception "The type initializer for 'OpenBabel.openbabel_csharpPINVOKE' threw an exception." why should be this

Comment: No details about the exception?

Answer (score 3):

We have written a C# tool for this:
http://chem4word.codeplex.com/
It has been developed over several years and works inside .NET and MS-WORD.